# What is the type annotation to use for a type annotation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

What type annotation do you use when a function is taking a type annotation as an argument?

**Why am I taking a type annotation as an argument?**

I have a function that tries to parse a string based on a type annotation.

E.g.

```
def get_appropriate_type_converter(type_annotation) -> Callable[[str], 'type_annotation']:
```

e.g.

```
get_appropriate_type_converter(Dict[str, int])("aaa:3,bbb:4") == dict(aaa=3, bbb=4)
```

And I want to type annotate this function.

Comment: How do you plan to use these type annotations as an argument? Can you provide an example implementation of `get_appropriate_type_converter`?

Comment: Well it's too big to post in comments, but it goes along the lines of: 
```if type_annotation is bool:
        return str2bool
    elif type_annotation in (int, float, str):
        return type_annotation
    elif inspect.isclass(type_annotation) and issubclass(type_annotation, IntEnum):
        return int```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a variable whose value is itself a type hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73763352/how-do-i-type-hint-a-variable-whose-value-is-itself-a-type-hint)

Answer (score 4):

from some investigation we can detect what type something like `Dict[str,int]` is:

```
>>> from typing import *
>>> x = Dict[str, int]
>>> type(x)
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
>>> y = Union[str, float]
>>> type(y)
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
```

So my guess is that you would use the annotation `typing._GenericAlias` to indicate you take a type alias, I don't have the tools on me to see if a linter confirms this.

Comment: hmm when I do it I get `<class 'typing.GenericMeta'>`.  (Python 3.6.11 - what version are you running)?

Comment: python 3.7, although `type(Dict[str,int])` will work for both versions, passing annotations is very unusual so it wouldn't surprise me if it is different name between versions.