# How do I type hint a variable whose value is itself a type hint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function one of whose arguments is expected to be a type hint: something like `typing.List`, or `typing.List[int]`, or even just `int`. Anything you would reasonably expect to see as a type annotation to an ordinary field.

What's the correct type hint to put on this argument?

(The context for this is that I'm writing a utility that works on classes that define fields using type annotations, a bit like the dataclass decorator.)

Comment: [`typing.TypeAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias)

Comment: @GinoMempin: It's the same question, but you'll note that it doesn't have an accepted answer. The unaccepted answer there does not solve the problem because: 1. It only covers a specific kind of type hint; and 2. It relies on a non-public part of the `typing` API.

Comment: @MechanicPig: `typing.TypeAlias` is something else - that's for when you want to define a shorthand for some complicated type hint, not for holding a type hint dynamically at run time. It's explicitly supposed to be used only at module top-level. We can tell that `TypeAlias` doesn't do what we want by checking how a linter behaves if you annotate an argument as `x: TypeAlias` - the linter (PyCharm, in my case) allows any value to be passed in for the argument, just as if it had no type hint at all.

Comment: "I have a function one of whose arguments is expected to be a type hint" What problem are you hoping to solve this way? Are you trying to reimplement Mypy in Python or something?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I'm writing something a bit like an ORM. I thought it would be neat to infer the "columns" from type annotations on the fields of user-defined classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer for Python 3.10:

Almost complete but less readable answer:

```
type | types.GenericAlias | types.UnionType | typing._BaseGenericAlias | typing._SpecialForm
```

Here are the possibilities of all types of annotations I can think of:

- Type object itself, such as `int`, `list`, etc. Corresponds to `type`.
- [Type hinting generics in standard collections](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/), such as `list[int]`. Corresponds to `types.GenericAlias`.
- [Types union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-union), such as `int | float` (but `typing.Union[int, float]` is not, it corresponds to the next item). Corresponds to `types.UnionType`.
- [Generic concrete collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generic-concrete-collections) in `typing`, such as `typing.List`, `typing.List[int]`, etc. Here I choose the common base class `typing._BaseGenericAlias` that first appeared in their inheritance chain. (In fact, not only these, but almost all subscriptible annotation classes in `typing` inherit from this class, including `typing.Literal[True]`, `typing.Union[int, float]`, etc.)
- [Special typing primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#special-typing-primitives) in typing, such as `typing.Any`, `typing.NoReturn`, etc. Corresponds to `typing._SpecialForm`.

It should be noted that the last two types begin with a single underline, indicating that they are internal types, and should not be imported and used from `typing`. However, they should be indispensable if you insist on completely covering all type annotations.

---

Python 3.11 update:

I noticed that `typing.Any` has changed from `typing._SpecialForm` to `typing._AnyMeta` (to allow inheritance of it), but it is now a `type` (which we have already included) and we don't need to add anything new to it.

`typing.Self` and `typing.LiteralString` have been added in 3.11, but they are both `typing._SpecialForm`, so there is also no need for anything new.

---

Python 3.12 update:

We now have a [`type` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#type), which allows us to create [`typing.TypeAliasType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAliasType) object, this seems to be the only new content.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm not super happy about the use of internal types, but I guess I can get around that by writing `type(typing.Any)` or so on. If nobody has a cleaner suggestion I'll accept this in a few hours.

Comment: @JEK Haha, actually, I don't want to use them either, but there seems to be no better way at present.

Answer (score 4):

Continuing from [@Mechanic Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17980931/mechanic-pig)'s answer (thx!), I created this abomination, which PyCharm and mypy (well kinda, I tested with python 3.11 + mypy 1.4.1) approve:

```py
from types import GenericAlias, UnionType
from typing import Any, Literal, TypeAlias

BaseGenericAlias: TypeAlias = type(Literal[0]).__base__.__base__  # type: ignore[name-defined]
SpecialForm: TypeAlias = type(Any)  # type: ignore[valid-type]
TypeHint: TypeAlias = (
    type  # type: ignore[valid-type]
    | GenericAlias
    | UnionType
    | BaseGenericAlias
    | SpecialForm
    | type(None)
)

# `type: ignore`s can be removed if mypy is not used
```

- `type(Literal[0]).__base__.__base__` resolves to `typing._BaseGenericAlias`
- `type(Any)` resolves to `typing._SpecialForm`

I also added `type(None)` because otherwise the snippet below doesn't work (real example would be a type hint for a function, that doesn't return anything):

```py
assert isinstance(None, TypeHint)
```

This whole thing was tested [like this](https://github.com/niqzart/pydantic-marshals/blob/804362f7cea7e682cc3a386f7b132e6a1038ddba/tests/unit/test_type_hint.py), again, python 3.11

Leaving this here for any future "typing the type hints" entrepreneurs, good luck

Comment: Good job, I would like to point out that `typing.Any` changed from `_SpecialForm` to `_AnyMeta` in python 3.11, so there may be missing types such as `NoReturn`.