# What is the type hint (or type annotation) of type hints (or type annotations)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, self-documenting-code

Consider the following Code:

```py
from typing import Union  # (or any other type hint, type Alias, etc.)

def func(arg: ???) -> None: 
    pass

func(Union[tuple[int, ...], float, "MyClass"])

class MyClass(object): 
    pass
```

The argument of function "func" is a type hint (or sometimes referred to as type annotation).
Now what kind of type hint (or type annotation) should I substitute the 3-question marks "???" with as the correct type hint (type annotation) for type hints (type annotations)?

So far: I've looked up python's doc but could not find my answere.
So it is either not covered in the doc or I simply didn't find it, yet.

Comment: Did you read [the intro for the typing module's docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#module-typing)? Beyond that, that page is chock full of various typing examples.

Comment: Here is a poorly readable but comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73763352/how-do-i-type-hint-a-variable-whose-value-is-itself-a-type-hint/73764101#73764101). I'm not sure if you're willing to accept it.

Comment: @MechanicPig this answeres my question on point and yes you are right: It seems not yet properly supported to type hint other type hints; 
As a consequence you have to list everything from which type hints may or may not could have been inherited.

Comment: @AKX yes of course I did. I already wrote in my original post that I read the doc first!

Comment: @Tom Sorry, then I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Type hints are syntax, not values, as they are intended to be processed outside of the Python runtime. `list[int]`, as a type hint, is not the same as the `GenericAlias` instance that `list[int]` evaluates to at runtime.